# Mudar o gravity do Hint - EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

No xml do meu edittext eu coloco a propriedade gravity para deixar o cursor sempre no fim, porém eu precisava deixar o hint do texto no começo.
É possível setar uma propriedade gravity para o texto e outra para o hint?
Segue o código xml do meu EditText:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtHorimetro"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:hint="Horimetro *"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtLitros"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtLitros"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtLitros" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Matheus,

Para o texto, vc pode usar o *setSelection*, por exemplo:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Dessa forma o Java vai verificar o texto que está digitado no campo, e vai colocar o cursor depois do ultimo caracter.